# How to select multiple cells in VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

The statement `If Target.Address = "$I$2" Then` selects just the I2 cell.

***How can I select the entire column instead of just one cell?*** Here is my code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$I$2" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: `Range()`

Comment: ok so like `range(I:I)`   ?

Comment: `If Target.Address = "$I$2" Then` does **not** select a cell. ... it only checks if Target's address is `I2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check the entire column "I" instead of cell "I2".
This condition shall be changed from

```
    If Target.Address = "$I$2" Then
```

to

```
    If Target.Column = 9 Then
```

So that macro will consider it for complete column.

Comment: you're a genius! thank you. Is there a way to select the entire sheet? or more than one column?

Comment: If you want to do it for complete sheet then just remove this condition. You will have to explain more than one part by suitable example as code may differ.

Comment: "You will have to explain more than one part by suitable example as code may differ." - Could I write ` If Target.Column = 9,10 Then` ? Should I copy and paste the code one column at a time?

Comment: There are many ways to write this e.g. `If Target.Column = 9 Or Target.Column = 10 Then` However this may become complicated when you have many such conditions.

Comment: @cucombrehombre - please accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: yes I would like to accept this answer. How do I do so? I don't see the accept button.

Comment: could someone give my question an upvote so I get the student badge? this is my second question.

Comment: @cucombrehombre I have upvoted the question. See if you can upvote now. To mark this as an answer see this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: shri- thaaaaaankk yooooouuuuu haha